# Preserving Transparent Background with Gaussian Blur in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur

Is there a method for preserving a transparent background with Gaussian blur in Adobe Illustrator?

When I use the Gaussian Blur effect on a stroke in illustrator (as instructed in [this tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/create-neon-text.html)), when I attempt to save as a GIF with a transparent background, the stroke background is white. I would expect the non-orange blur of the stroke in the below to be transparent.

[image: Gaussian Blur with white background]

Any thoughts on preserving the transparency?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Illustrator. The problem is with the GIF format itself. It only supports full transparency or no transparency, with nothing in between. Use PNG instead if you want support for alpha transparency.

Answer (score 2):

Partial transparency is not possible in GIFs, the format supports only fully opaque colors and full transparency. You want what's called alpha transparency. APNG, that's Animated PNG, is one possible alternative format for you. And there's more. Check this link https://ezgif.com/help/alternative-animated-image-formats